# How to remove special characters in ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, special-characters

I have created a web service method in Asp.Net and getting a response in XML.
In the response there are too many special characters.

How to deal with these special character, because I am getting errors like this:

```
"Specified value has Invalid CRLF characters"
```

Which method do I use? Is HttpUtility good for this one?

If yes, is there a sample?

My code: I am using `Regex.Replace` but getting an error:

```
  string link = "http://xxx.xx.x";
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
  request.Connection = Regex.Replace(newstr.m12345(str, name, pwd, id), "[^\"a-zA-Z0-9_?<>+=./: -]", "");
  string connection = request.Connection;
  return connection;
```

Comment: @JohnStephen Thnx man, I saw that link, about CData, but not clearly perfect!!can you show me by example?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the answer, with the help of using **XDocument**.

```
string link = "http://xxx.xx.x";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(newstr.m12345(str, name, pwd, id));
string connection = Convert.ToString(doc);
return connection;
```